# Downsides of too much memory

Tags: sql-server

What are the downsides of a SQL Server with a lot of memory, e.g. several TB. In SQL Server 2022 there is the new feature called parallel buffer pool scan. Will that solve all the downsides of several TB of memory or only some of the downsides?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What are the downsides of a SQL Server with a lot of memory, e.g. several TB.

It depends on the workload and application, but in general for SQL Server here are a list of items to be concerned about:

- Process memory mutex getting hot (Windows specific)
- Heap serialization getting hot (Windows specific)
- NUMA localities with hardware layout
- Anything that would require a kernel dump
- 3rd party applications (such as drivers, security, or infrastructure usage)

SQL Specific issues that may arise:

- Operations that require buffer pool scans (checkpoint, drop database/file, backups, restores, certain AG related items)
- Queries that need tuned for memory usage (frequent allocations/deallocations)
- Anything that goes external (preemptive)
- 3rd party libraries
- Anything that would require a use mode dump
- 3rd party applications (for example, auditing apps that use VirtaulAlloc)

> In SQL Server 2022 there is the new feature called parallel buffer pool scan. Will that solve all the downsides of several TB of memory or only some of the downsides?

This will help in various situations, where it can, but your mileage will vary based on various factors. Obviously, anything that is parallelized will use more computing resources, if those exist then great... but if they don't, it could lead to other issues.

Comment: The maximum size of the plan cache depends on the amount of memory and I think there might be some problems with this also but I am not sure...

Comment: There's a hard limit on number of entries in the plan cache, which you'll generally hit before exhausting memory on a large box. @khr489

Answer (score 0):

> What is the biggest SQL Server you have seen in terms of number of cores, memory and data?

At one job, I managed a few SQL Servers that each had databases totaling a few terabytes of data. The largest single table in one of those databases was about 1 terabyte big itself, with a few 10s of billions of rows in it. The servers were provisioned with 8 CPU cores, and 16 GB of Memory. Eventually we bumped up the Memory to 32 GB.

*Believe it or not*, this was sufficient provisioning for the use cases of the servers. Most of the data was historical, and most of the use cases only needed to read a small fraction of the data at any given time (by date range). Properly architected and indexed tables, with carefully crafted queries that mostly used index seeks were key. For some analytical use cases that spanned larger amounts of data, columnstore indexes served the purpose for really well.

> What are the downsides of a SQL Server with a lot of memory, e.g. several TB. In SQL Server 2022 there is the new feature of parallel buffer pool scan. Will that solve all the downsides of several TB of memory or only some of the downsides?

To my knowledge and in my opinion there are none, though I've never had to work with a server that had a use case for terabytes of Memory. From reading about the feature of parallel buffer pool scan, it sounds like it's an improvement to make scanning large amounts of data in Memory faster. But I wouldn't say that means without it large amounts of Memory is inherently a problem. Scanning large amounts of data is the problem, and doing it in Memory is usually going to be faster than doing it on Disk. But there's still a limit to how fast terabytes of data can be scanned, so it sounds like this new feature improves that limitation.

Comment: Some operations, e.g. checkpoint, need to scan the buffer pool and too much memory will slow things down. I am sure there are other problems with TBs of memory and I think one of them is related to the plan cache, but I am not sure...

Comment: @xhr489 "*Some operations, e.g. checkpoint, need to scan the buffer pool and too much memory will slow things down.*" - Again that sounds more like a *too much data* problem not too much Memory problem. If a server is provisioned with 1 terabyte of Memory but SQL Server is only actively using 1 GB of it, then operations like checkpoint should not be affected.

Comment: Of course you want more memory in order to cache more data. If you only have 1GB of data why would you want to have 1TB of memory...?

Comment: @xhr489 There are multiple reasons I could give, one being CLR, but that's regardless of the point. The point is it's a data problem not a Memory problem, just wanted to be clear. Even if SQL Server was actively using 1 TB of Memory but for things other than data (e.g. CLR) then checkpoint operations would still be fast. (Of course if you're using 1 TB of Memory for CLR, you probably have other problems worth discussing.)